# How do I enable JavaScript type checking in Vue files on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

I have found the settings in Visual Studio Code to enable type checking for JavaScript in JS files. Such that: [Bad code is highlighted and it also shows the reason why it's bad code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ks1A.png)

This behavior does not occur for JavaScript code in Vue files. I have searched through all the settings in Visual Studio Code. I have scoured the internet for any extension that can do this for me to no avail.

How can I make my Vue files type-check the JavaScript in them?

Comment: Do you use the extension called Vetur? I think it has a javascript linter on it

Comment: I have Vetur installed.

Comment: I have Vetur installed.
Type checking works perfectly well in js files but it doesn't work for vue.js files.

I searched for extensions named "vue" and the first one I found says this:

"
Sorry for the bad news: ES2015 support is still buggy.

When using embeded <script> JavaScript code can not trigger VSC's JavaScript language support. That means Intellisense won't work with embeded <script> tags.
"

I'm willing to change IDEs if necessary. But it has to be free.
If it's impossible to get type checking for js code in vue files, can any1 recommend a free IDE that does it.

Comment: how do you use vue.js? do you use nuxt or vue.js CLI? if you have vetur it should usually highlight

Comment: I use nuxt. Vetur helps to write vue code. It does nothing about the javascript code on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

LOL. I found the answer.
All I had to do was add //@ts-check directly underneath the script tag and type checking was enabled.
So HAPPY!!!
Thank you, everyone, for your input

Comment: That shouldn't be needed and probably represents something missing in your setup.

Comment: I noticed other issues with Visual Studio Code and I now use webstorm.
Solved so many issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

For best results I'd suggest starting a new project using `vue-cli` and selecting the options for TypeScript and ESLint. You'll also need the ESLint extension for VS Code.

Here's a [helpful blog post](https://blog.totominc.io/linting-vue-typescript-eslint-prettier/) showing the parts of this process.

Once you have a nicely working setup with the clean project, then move the code over. I suggest this because getting all the config right can be a mess with an existing project.